# Why is OpenGL vendor 'Mesa Project'

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, vnc, opengl

I'm trying to develop code for OpenGL 2, on Nvidia card, but for some reason my OpenGL version is 1.4, and vendor is `Mesa Project` instead of `Nvidia`.

```
OpenGL vendor string: Mesa Project
OpenGL renderer string: Software Rasterizer
OpenGL version string: 1.4 (2.1 Mesa 9.2.0-devel)
```

I installed and reinstalled latest nvidia drivers (http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/132546/en-us).

Running `ldd $(which glxinfo)` gives:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff53533000)
libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/nvidia-390/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f99e8020000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f99e7ce6000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f99e791c000)
libnvidia-tls.so.390.46 => /usr/lib/nvidia-390/tls/libnvidia-tls.so.390.46 (0x00007f99e7718000)
libnvidia-glcore.so.390.46 => /usr/lib/nvidia-390/libnvidia-glcore.so.390.46 (0x00007f99e5918000)
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f99e5706000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f99e5502000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f99e52e0000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f99e835d000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f99e4fd7000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f99e4dd3000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f99e4bcd000)
```

So it seems to be using the correct nvidia libs.

Some more info:

- I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.
- **Might be important** - I'm connected to the server by VNC to a gateway station, and `ssh -X` from the gateway station to the server.

Any idea why Nvidia OpenGL is not being used?

Comment: _Where_ is the NVidia card installed, in this configuration? Local client, gateway, or on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the GPU is not being used for rendering in your use case. As the `glxinfo` output you posted shows, the *Software Rasterizer* is being used for GL rendering to the X DISPLAY in question (presumably the forwarded display via ssh, which means glxinfo is querying the X server on the gateway for GL information).

Comment: Thanks for your help! The Nvidia card is on the server. So why is the GPU not being used for rendering? Is it because the VNC or the SSH? What if I'll do VNC directly to the server? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the GPU is not being used because X11 is not running on the GPU. It is running on the gateway, and so glxinfo is querying the X11 server on your gateway (as described in the answer). The glxinfo program does not directly query hardware, but queries the X11 server and gives you information about what that X11 server is using.

Comment: Thanks. Some progress at last! When switching to VNC directly to the server I get: `OpenGL vendor string: Mesa project: www.mesa3d.org
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa GLX Indirect
OpenGL version string: 1.3 Mesa 4.0.4` Still Mesa though. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Plug in a monitor and run direct on the hardware you want it to appear on. The problem is you are expecting something which depends on X11 to guide you on what your program which may interact directly with the hardware. Again, `glxinfo` tells you what the X11 server you're running under is using for GL. It doesn't tell you what an arbitrary program not using X11 might use.

Comment: @dobey thanks for your answer, it helped me to understand my problem better too. Friend, do you know how to let X11 to run on the GPU?

Comment: @MJimitater run it on a system with a GPU. How is it not using the GPU? Are you trying to run an X11 session remotely?

Comment: @dobey thanks for your reply, sorry I was unclear: I was trying to use Nvidia's offloading to do the heavy lifting, letting it be the X11 vendor. I figured out now by setting up offloading. Thanks friend!